# Python - Splitting dictionary into dictionaries with the same values?

Tags: python, dictionary

Say I have a dictionary with many items that have the same values; for example:

```
dict = {'hello':'a', 'goodbye':'z', 'bonjour':'a', 'au revoir':'z', 'how are you':'m'}
```

How would I split the dictionary into dictionaries (in this case, three dictionaries) with the same values? In the example, I want to end up with this:

```
dict1 = {'hello':'a', 'bonjour':'a'}
dict2 = {'goodbye':'z', 'au revoir':'z'}
dict3 = {'how are you':'m'}
```

Comment: `from itertools import groupby`

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to just turn this into a dict of lists? e.g. `{'a': ['hello', 'bonjour'], 'z': ['goodbye', 'au revoir'], 'm': ['how are you']}`
Also, you really need to show what you've tried and what issues you're having if you want help.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to collect by the common values, then create `dict` objects for each group within a list comprehension.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> import operator
>>> by_value = operator.itemgetter(1)
>>> [dict(g) for k, g in groupby(sorted(d.items(), key = by_value), by_value)]
[{'hello': 'a', 'bonjour': 'a'},
 {'how are you': 'm'},
 {'goodbye': 'z', 'au revoir': 'z'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way without importing any modules is as follows:

```
def split_dict(d):
    unique_vals = list(set(d.values()))
    split_dicts = []
    for i in range(len(unique_vals)):
        unique_dict = {}
        for key in d:
            if d[key] == unique_vals[i]:
                unique_dict[key] = d[key]
        split_dicts.append(unique_dict)
    return split_dicts
```

For each unique value in the input dictionary, we create a dictionary and add the key values pairs from the input dictionary where the value is equal to that value. We then append each dictionary to a list, which is finally returned.